# Open a default folder path in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

**Issue:**

- Office is a folder in internal memory of Android.
- Clicking a button in screen should always take one to default folder, Office.

Appreciate help as no accepted answers found.

Comment: There is no "open a folder" in Android.

Comment: You can't open a specific folder using `intent`, but you can make your app shows the content of this folder

Comment: I have to load a file from this Office folder. Have to set this folder's path as Default

Comment: Verily, that would be of much help , do you have any code sample, @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI ?

Comment: File.listFiles() and put result in adapter for ListView or AlertDialog.

Comment: Thank you, CommonsWare, Mouaad , blackapps !  Fixed the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In onActivityResult:**

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (data == null)
            return;

        if (requestCode == viewfilerequestcode){

                Uri Fileuri = data.getData();
                String DFLocation="/mnt/sdcard/Office/";
                String FilePath="";

                if (FilePath.trim().equals(DFLocation.concat(GettheFilename(Fileuri))))
                {
                        FilePath = DFLocation.concat(GettheFilename(Fileuri));

                }
......
.......
........
}
.........
..........

}
```

**Intent start:**

```
        btnview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent fileintent;

                String[] mimestoview =
                        {"application/msword", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", // .doc & .docx };

                fileintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT); 

                fileintent.setType("*/*");
                fileintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimestoview );
                fileintent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                fileintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                fileintent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                try {
                    startActivityForResult(fileintent, viewfilerequestcode);

                  
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    lbl.setText("No activity to handle picking a file. Showing alternatives.");
                }

            }

        });
```